# My Macbook Pro WiFi is getting slower unless I reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, sleep-wake

So I have that new Macbook Pro 15 inch with the Nvidia GPU for 6 months or so, and recently I experienced WiFi slowdown after I let my Macbook on for hours (with putting it to sleep by closing the screen) my WiFi gets waaaay slower. It's not my internet since when I test it with another computer, everything's normal. And when I reboot my Macbook, it also get back to normal download speed.

It just happened one day like 5 days ago when I was trying to do a Twitch stream. Maybe it's something I have installed ? I don't think it comes from OpenBroadcaster ? Or from JackAudio or Soundflower (two packages that simulates virtual sound playback so I can stream what my Macbook outputs, I did uninstall the second but I really don't know how to uninstall JackAudio) ?

Answer (score 1):

I only address uninstalling Jack Audio.

You can uninstall Jack by looking here: http://www.jackosx.com/Documentation.pdf

Uninstalling Jack OS X
To uninstall Jack OS X, double click the “Uninstall JackOSX” file located in the Jack
folder, in your main Applications folder. A Terminal window will be displayed, and it will
prompt you for your Mac’s Administrator password. Type it, press Return, and all
components of Jack OS X will be removed from your system. Please note that when
typing your password into the Terminal window, it will not seem as though your
password is being acknowledged; this is not the case – just keep typing and press
Return, and it will work.
If you’d like to uninstall a previous version of Jack OS X, this is done automatically for
you when installing the new version.